# How to make VS Code treat files without extension as a certain language?

Tags: visual-studio-code

At work there are a lot of file without extension. They are all COBOL files, so now I manually change their associating to COBOL each time I open one. But I was looking for a way to make VS Code treat files without extension as COBOL automatically.

I know you can add file associations in the settings, but the only thing that works is to add `"*": "COBOL"` there, but then everything is considered a COBOL file... I also tried `"[^.]": "COBOL" hoping regex would work but it didn't.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can apply the file associations to all files in a [given directory only](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_common-questions):

```
"files.associations": {
    "**/RootDir/**/*": "COBOL"
}
```

This way, all files in `/RootDir/`, or one of it's sub-directories, will be mapped to COBOL.
All files outside of `/RootDir/` will still be mapped as usual according to their extensions.

Suppose your `/RootDir/` doesn't contain only COBOL-files, but also some other file types. In this case you can go further and define exceptions for the file associations:

```
"files.associations": {
    "**/RootDir/**/*.bat": "bat",
    "**/RootDir/**/*.sh": "shellscript",
    "**/RootDir/**/*": "COBOL"
}
```

Basically you're instructing Visual Studio Code to map all files in `/RootDir/` to COBOL, except for `.bat` and `.sh` which are mapped as Batch and Shellscript, respectively.
As above, all files outside of `/RootDir/` will still be mapped as usual according to their extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same problem with `php_cs-fixer` config file.
This one is generally `.php_cs`.

I only have to add this line

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.php_cs": "php"
},
```

**AND relaunch vscode** and .php_cs is now a php formatted file.
hope this help.

Comment: Relaunching was the key for me

Answer (score 0):

Just found another possible solution which works best for me.
I was trying to get shell lang selected for the .ssh/config and it worked by just adding

```
#!shellscript
```

at the very beginning of the file, maybe this doesn't work with all files/languages but it can be useful

Answer (score 0):

A quick and updated solution using vscode 1.79 for PUNCTUAL files

Open any text file you want to read as a particular language, go to bottom right corner and hover the options. There is one that reads "Select language mode" (3rd from right in my case). Click there and select the language you want your file to be treated like.

[image]